# websphere wsadmin.sh -f file vs interactive

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

Have a strange problem with jython script execution in WAS70 (solaris):
wsadmin.sh in interactive mode versus with -f  option.

AdminConfig.show('') works in the interactive mode of the wsadmin.sh
but it doesn't show any output when run with wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f ./

I suspect something is not loaded when used with wsadmin.sh -f

what is the difference running wsadmin.sh in interactive mode like
/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython 
versus
/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f ./

How do I determine what is being loaded(like property files) in both mode?

Thx
Ronin

Comment: There should be no difference. Can you update your question with your specific commands, scripts and output?

Comment: this is the command...: AdminConfig.show('<listener_port_name>(cells/<cell_name>/nodes/<node_name>/servers/<server_name>|server.xml#ListenerPort_1337071014049)')

Comment: It seems to be a shell-quoting related issue. Try this: wsadmin.sh -lang jython -c "AdminConfig.show('put_config_id_here')"

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea...

1. Make sure you use "-lang jython" when you call wsadmin
2. Do you just use "AdminConfig.show('')" in the script?

   If you do, I think you need "print AdminConfig.show('')" else the string the command returns goes nowhere.